# Ambiguity of $k$-vector in solid state physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

It is known that $k$-vector is defined up to a reciprocal lattice vector.
So we can write, in the one-dimensional case,
$$k'=k+ \frac{n\pi} {a}.$$
But this corresponds to a completely different wavelength and energy! In fact, energy is infinite for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Is it normal after all?

Answer (score 1):

$k$ is not the usual momentum. It is what is called the *Bloch momentum* or *crystal momentum*. The value of $\mathcal E$ in an energy band  takes that same value at $k$ and $k$+plus a reciprocal-lattice vector. See the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_momentum.

Comment: It is equal only for specific values of $k$. OK I think I got, I can't use the dispersion relation for free electrons right ?

Comment: @user1364012 Yes. The energy   ${\mathcal E}({\bf k}$ is a periodic function that is quite different from the free ${\mathcal E}= \hbar^2 |k|^2/2m$,

Comment: Is there any physical insight why electrons with the different wavelength have the same energy ?

Comment: @user1364012  It's just Bloch's (or Floquet's)  theorem: the actual wavefunction is $\psi({\bf r}) =e^{i{\bf k}\cdot {\bf r}} u_{\bf k}({\bf r})$ where $u_{\bf k}$ has the periodicity of the lattice. As a consequence ${\bf k}$ and ${\bf k}$ plus a reciprocal lattice vector are the same   wavefunction up to a change of phase-choice for the $u_{\bf k}$, and therefore the same quantum state and hence the same energy.